# What widget is better to use for 2 pages app in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to create an app with 2 pages. I would like to switch between the two pages using a button: when a button is pressed the page switches. My code does not seem to work. I might be missing something.
How can I achieve this?

This is the code I am working with:

```
<TrafGridLayout>:
    PageLayout:
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'

            BoxLayout:
                TextInput:
                    text: ''

            BoxLayout:
                TextInput:
                    text: ''

            # Calculate and show page #2
            BoxLayout:
                Button:
                    text: "Calculate"
                    on_press:
                        traffictax.calculate(point_from.text, point_to.text)
                        traffictax.show_page(1)

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'

            # Show page #1
            BoxLayout:
                Button:
                    text: "Back to first page"
                    on_press: traffictax.show_page(0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Question 1

> My code does not seem to work. I might be missing something.

## Problem

Running the app with the code provided, displayed a small window at the bottom left hand corner.

### Root Cause

1. The class rule, `<TrafGridLayout>:` is missing either `cols` or `rows` attribute.
2. In `PageLayout`, transitions from one page to the next are made by swiping in from the border areas on the right or left hand side. Therefore, it is not a best practice to use `Button` widget's `on_press` event for this.

#### [Kivy GridLayout » constraint cols or rows](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.gridlayout.html#background)

> A GridLayout must always have at least one input constraint:
>   [GridLayout.cols](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.gridlayout.html#kivy.uix.gridlayout.GridLayout.cols) or [GridLayout.rows](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.gridlayout.html#kivy.uix.gridlayout.GridLayout.rows).

#### [Kivy » PageLayout](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.pagelayout.html)

> The [PageLayout](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.pagelayout.html#kivy.uix.pagelayout.PageLayout) class is used to create a simple multi-page
>   layout, in a way that allows easy flipping from one page to another
>   using borders.
>
> Transitions from one page to the next are made by swiping in from the
>   border areas on the right or left hand side.

### Solution - kv

Add `cols: 1` to class rule, `<TrafGridLayout>:`

#### Snippets

```
<TrafGridLayout>:
    cols: 1

    PageLayout:
```

### Output

[image: PageLayout - Page 1]
[image: PageLayout - Page 2]

## Question 2

> I would like to switch between the two pages using a button: when a
>   button is pressed the page switches.

### Solution

Use Kivy [ScreenManager](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html) and button pressed to switch page.

## Example

The following example illustrates the use of Kivy ScreenManager and one of button's events, `on_press` to switch page / screen.

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass


class FirstPage(Screen):

    def calculate(self, point_from, point_to):
        print("point_from={0}, point_to={1}".format(point_from, point_to))


class SecondPage(Screen):
    pass


class TestApp(App):
    title = "Login Screen"

    def build(self):
        return ScreenManagement()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

### test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<ScreenManagement>:
    FirstPage:
        id: page1
    SecondPage:

<FirstPage>:
    name: "first_page"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        BoxLayout:
            Label:
                text: "Point From:"
            TextInput:
                id: point_from
                text: ''

        BoxLayout:
            Label:
                text: "Point To:"
            TextInput:
                id: point_to
                text: ''

        # Calculate and show page #2
        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                text: "Calculate"
                on_press:
                    root.calculate(point_from.text, point_to.text)
                    root.manager.current = "second_page"


<SecondPage>:
    name: "second_page"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        # Show page #1
        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                text: "Back to first page"
                on_press: root.manager.current = "first_page"
```

### Output

[image: Figure 1 - App Startup]
[image: Figure 2 - Points Entered]
[image: Figure 3 - Page Two Displayed]
[image: Figure 4 - Back to Page One]